# Automate Grouping & Summarisation in R

Tags: r, automation, grouping, summarization

I am looking for advice on how to automate the large number grouping and summarization tasks.

I perform dplyr grouping of 4 columns and then summarise the fifth column based on that. There are 936 combinations of the 4 columns names I group by. It means I would need to execute the grouping & summarization 936 times.

The data frame:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  type     from     to      name    price    
  a        abc      xyz     new     10
  a        abc      xyz     new     15
  a        abc      xyz     new     11
  a        abc      xyz     new     12
  a        abc      xyz     new     10
  a        efg      hce     old     13  
  a        efg      hce     old     14  
  a        efg      hce     old     15  
  b        abc      hce     old     18
  b        abc      hce     old     19
  b        abc      hce     old     25
  b        abc      ijk     new     20 
  b        abc      ijk     new     25   
  b        efg      ijk     old     12
  b        efg      ijk     old     18
  b        efg      ijk     old     14
  b        efg      ijk     old     12
  b        efg      lmn     old     13
  b        efg      lmn     old     18
  b        efg      lmn     old     19
  b        efg      lmn     old     19
")
```

The grouping and summarization:

```
file_1 <- mydata %>% filter(type=="a" & from=="abc" & to=="xyz" & name="new") %>%  group_by(price) %>% summarise(price=median(price), n=n())
```

....

```
file_n <- mydata %>% filter(type=="b" & from=="efg" & to=="lmn" & name="old") %>% group_by(price) %>% summarise(price=median(price), n=n())
```

The output file_1 contains 2 variables: 1. all prices, 2. number of occurrences of the respective prices:

```
head(file_1)
```

The number of the first 4 variables names combinations, and the number of output files:

```
n_combinations <- mydata %>% group_by(type, from, to, name) %>% summarise(n=n())
dim(n_combinations)[1]
```

There are hundreds of different prices for each combination in the real file.

I understand it is not practical to create 936 output files but I wonder how would you approach such a task. I was considering a sample of up to 100 combinations for my analysis.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that

```
mydata %>% 
  group_by(type, from, to, name) %>% 
  summarise(price=median(price), .groups="drop")
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  type  from  to    name  price
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
1 a     abc   xyz   new    11  
2 a     efg   hce   old    13.5
3 b     abc   hce   old    18  
4 b     abc   ijk   new    20  
5 b     efg   ijk   old    12  
6 b     efg   lmn   old    13
```

Does what you want and is robust to new combinations of `type`, `from` and `name`.  If you don't want every possible combination, you can just filter the results dataset.

Welcome to SO and well done for producing a better simple self-contained minimal working example than most new users manage!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  I forgot to add group_by(price) in the code. I have corrected it. Sorry.

Comment: After I have corrected the code, it is a different question now. I apologize for any inconvenience, I should have checked the code properly before posting.